# Append string at the end of line using sed

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, sed

I want to append the below string at the end of all lines in a file. I tried to search on web but could not get anything relevant. I used the below command too

```
sed -i -e "s?$?\$dest \$port \$fgt --pin '\$limit' --nogui;"? ipv42
```

Can someone please help me I want to append the below string in end of all lines in a file

```
$dest $port $fgt --pin '\$limit' --nogui;
```

Comment: Replace it with what? Or do you mean to append that text at the end of each line?

Comment: Sorry I mean to append the text at the end of each line

Comment: @seshoumara I have edited the post

Comment: Is it `\$limit` or `$limit` you want in the replacement?

Answer (score 2):

One way can be using the heredoc, backslashed to inhibit variable expansion. What we are doing is providing a fully quoted string(multiline) heredoc.

```
sed -f - <<\_SED_ inputfile 
s?$?$dest $port $fgt --pin '$limit' --nogui;?
_SED_
```

Answer (score 1):

Your sed script is almost working, except:

1. the last delimiter of the s command, `?`, should be inside the quotes
2. you need to escape `$` in the search part, because shell interprets `$?` as being the exit status of the last executed command.

Correct command:

```
sed -i -e "s?\$?\$dest \$port \$fgt --pin '\$limit' --nogui;?" ipv42
```

Comment: Or use single quotes (except for the literal single quotes) for quoting: `sed -i 's/$/$dest $port $fgt --pin '\''$limit'\'' --nogui;/' ipv42`

Comment: Good point. With single quotes you get rid of those pesky bash interpretations of the command before it reaches sed, I'm surprised the OP used `?` as the delimiter of the search command in the first place.

Comment: In this case, there is no real reason to use `?` as the delimiter for the `s` command. Note too the requested escaping of the last `$`.